# Separating the integral of a product of functions apart

Tags: functional-analysis

> Show that $$\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x+t))^2(K_n(t))^2\mathop{dt}\right)^{1/2}\leq \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x+t))^2\mathop{dt}\right)^{1/2}$$ where $K_n(t)$ is Fejer's kernel.

I have this following integral:

$$\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x+t))^2(K_n(t))^2\mathop{dt}\right)^{1/2}$$

Is there a way to break this up so I can have something of the form:

$$\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f((x+t))^2\mathop{dt}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K_n(t)\mathop{dt}\right)^{1/2}$$

I would like it in this form, because I know that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K_n(t)\mathop{dt} =1$. I thought at first applying Cauchy-Schwarz would be helpful, but then I realized that for me to make use of the inequality, the exponent $2$ needed to be over everything, including the integral- not just the integrand. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where did this inequality come from?

Comment: It is an exercise in Carothers' *Real Analysis*